# How to use array values in SQL query in PHP_MySQL

Tags: php, html, mysql

I am taking multiple values from user from a drop down list. I stored those values in an array in php. Everything is fine. Now I want to use these array values to query my database to give the desired results.
My html code is

```
<select multiple name="equipment[]">
    <option  value="all">ALL</option>
    <option  value="helmet">HEMLMET</option>
    <option  value="boots">BOOTS</option>
    <option  value="jacket">JACKET</option>
    <option  value="flask">FLASK</option>
</select>
```

```
$equipment=$_POST['equipment'];
```

I used this piece to store values.

Now based on one or more values in the array; I want filter my query.

```
Select w,x,y,z from table_a inner join table_b where table_a.w="the values in array";
```

I tried using foreach to loop through, but its taking only the last value.
thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's the IN clause you are looking for:

```
select * from tableA inner join on tableB on ... where tableA.w in ('value1', 'value2')
```

You can use a loop or implode() function in php to generate the in clause. Just be mindful that if you select only 1 item in the control, then $_POST['equipment'] will be a string, not an array. So, use is_array() to determine if multiple values were selected.

Answer (score 3):

Keep in mind that HTML, PHP, and MySQL are three different processing environments, so none of them share the same memory (variables) or code (e.g. loops).

Roughly in order:

1. **HTML** can "pass" values **to PHP** through URLs and form posts (and other HTTP methods)
2. **PHP** can "pass" values **to MySQL** by printing its variables into the MySQL "query string" (**[beware of MySQL string injection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)**)
3. **MySQL** returns its data **to PHP**, based on the query string, through the query engine.
4. **PHP** can "pass" values **to HTML** by printing its variables into the HTML output.

So, to get the variable selections to MySQL from PHP, you need to compose a "query string" that looks for all of the answers.

It will look something like this:

```
SELECT w,x,y,z
FROM table_a
INNER JOIN table_b
WHERE table_a.w IN ('helmet', 'boots', 'jacket');
```

See [MySQL Expression syntax](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/expressions.html) for more help on this.

To build it, you will need to be VERY CAREFUL to read the "MySQL string injection"  (where a person using your web page can change the calls your database makes) question linked above, since you are taking the values from the "user"/"client" (through a URL or form post).

The answers to [Can I bind an array to an IN() condition?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/920353/can-i-bind-an-array-to-an-in-condition) have some good suggestions for how to build a query string with array values while preventing injection attacks.

Answer (score 0):

```
<form action='somepage.php' method='POST'>
    .
    .
    <select multiple name="equipment[]">
        <option  value="all">ALL</option>
        <option  value="helmet">HEMLMET</option>
        <option  value="boots">BOOTS</option>
        <option  value="jacket">JACKET</option>
        <option  value="flask">FLASK</option>
    </select>
    .
    .
</form>
```

**somepage.php**

```
<?
$equipment=$_POST['equipment'];

$TotalEquipment=sizeof($equipment); //Count total number of equipements selected
$values=""; //initialize values as empty.

for($i=0;$i<$TotalEquipment;$i++)
{
    $valu=$equipment[$i];
    if($i==0)
    {
        $values="'".$valu."',";
    }
    else
    {
        $values=$values."'".$valu."',";
    }
}

$values=rtrim($values, ","); //For removing last comma (,) from the string

$Query="SELECT w,x,y,z 
        FROM table_a
        INNER JOIN table_b
        WHERE table_a.w IN ($values)";

//Here, execute your $Query with appropriate mysql functions

?>
```

Enjoy Coding. Cheers.